# NSDateFormatter problem with weekday EEE

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

Why does the following code output: Dday: (null)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Sun 15:00:00"];
DLog(@"Ddate: %@", date);
```

If I use the format HH:mm:ss and string 15:00:00 i get a valid date...

Cheers mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be related to the locale of your system/device, have a look at the following from apple

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2010/qa1480.html

Comment: I lost nearly 2 hours on this... finally you came over! Thanks

Comment: The link is broken. Can you provide a new one?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it should be EEE not eee? I was using eee and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah pretty sure since the standards suggests EEE and when going date to string EEE is working like a charm.