# parsing date works on simulator not iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator, nsdateformatter

I have the following code to parse a date from string:

```
NSString * str = @"8/13/2010 1:59:00 PM";
NSDateFormatter * dateFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
NSDate * orderDate = [dateFormat2 dateFromString:str ];
```

but orderDate is always coming up null, what am i doing wrong ? What is the proper dateFormatString ?

This works fine in the emulator but is null on iphone 4 ios 4.0

Comment: I believe the answer is covered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600748/nsdateformatter-problem-with-weekday-eee/3600924#3600924

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this fix from @Liam 's comment helped me fix this, i'm just posting in case its helpful to someone else,

```
NSDateFormatter * parser = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale * locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]autorelease];
[parser setLocale:locale ];
[parser setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[parser setDateFormat:@"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];

NSDate * orderDate = [parser dateFromString:str ];
```

i realized this bug i found only happens when the iphone user sets their clock to the 24 hour military time,

Comment: Changing the format string to `H:mm:ss` should make it compatible with hours from 0-23.

Comment: Also, if the date/time value you are getting is dependent on the user's preference settings, you'll probably be better off using the `setDateStyle:` method instead of `setDateFormat:`.

Comment: @highlycaffeinated  - i don't want to display it as 0-23, also do you have an example on how to use setDateStyle?

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the date format, it's that the `init` method is only supported on Mac OS X v10.4 through Mac OS X v10.5 (which is probably why it works in the simulator).  Try using

`initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:`

instead.  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: @slim Sorry, I was looking at the OS X docs instead of the iOS docs.  init is indeed the method to use on iOS.